# MySQL UPDATE query with subquery taking forever

Tags: sql, performance, mysql

I have a MySQL UPDATE query which takes a long time to complete. Am I missing a much simpler way to achieve the same result?

```
"UPDATE table2, table1
SET table2.id_occurrences = (SELECT SUM(IF(id = table2.id, 1, 0)) FROM table1)
WHERE table2.id = table1.id;"
```

- `table2` contains all possible values of `id`, exactly one record for each.
- `table1` contains some values of `id`, but there are multiple records of some values.
- I need to update records in `table2` to show the number of occurrences of the corresponding value of `id` in `table1`. The above query does the job, but it takes about 3 minutes when table1 contains 500 records, and `table2` 30,000 records. I have much bigger tables to process so this is too long :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid subqueries, use joins:

```
UPDATE table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table2.id = table1.id)
SET table2.id_occurrences = COUNT(table1.id)
GROUP BY table2.id
```

Oh, UPDATE doesn't support GROUP BY. Try this query:

```
UPDATE table2
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table1 GROUP BY id
) AS t1
ON (table2.id = t1.id)
SET table2.id_occurrences = t1.cnt
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a particular reason to avoid subqueries?

I'd be interested to see the difference in speed between this method and Brian's/Jonathan's, which brought the query time down from 150s to 20s, but I get the following error with the syntax:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY table2.id' at line 4`

Comment: Dependent subquery in WHERE is executed for each row of main query, that can result in a rather big number of additional queries. It's best to rewrite query as JOIN. I made up that query, looks like UPDATE doesn't support GROUP BY. So I will give you a query with JOINed subquery soon . Joined subquery is executed only once.

Comment: What's an execution time of this query?

Comment: Wow, that works and it's super quick! Only 70s to complete when using a 4,000,000 entries in table1 and 30,000 in table2.
I wasn't being lazy, just couldn't get it to work using the MySQL docs. I'm fine with any other language docs, but MySQL always throws me :D
Thanks for your help.

Comment: On the smaller tables that took 20s with the above method, this took 1.7s. The performance hit seems to increase exponentially with table size though, which makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

I think your join on the update is perhaps not necessary...

```
UPDATE table2
    SET table2.id_occurrences = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
                                     WHERE table2.id = table1.id);
```

Comment: Indeed. And make sure you've got indexes on the id columns in each table.

Comment: Ah yes, that's much quicker. I see now, I'm not even updating table1. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for something like:

```
UPDATE table2
SET id_occurrences = (SELECT count(*) FROM table1
                      WHERE table1.id = table2.id)
```

Comment: If I could accept this answer too, I would. Thanks for the help, Brian just got there first :)

Comment: He did indeed! And with almost identical code. Great minds think alike, they say. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table2, table1 
SET table2.id_occurrences = (SELECT SUM(IF(id = table2.id, 1, 0)) FROM table1) 
WHERE table2.id in (select distinct table1.id from table1) AND table2.id = table1.id;
```