# MYSQL : SET value in an UPDATE query when all conditions of subquery are satisfied

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

**Problem**

There are 2 tables DEALS and DEAL_DETAILS.

DEALS table contains title and other generic information about the deal.

DEAL_DETAILS table contains information on different time ranges at which deal has to be shown, address specific to deal etc.,

I have abstracted the columns we need to focus on and have attached the schema below.

**What I need to achieve is-**

When **ALL** *status*-es of a particular *dealid* in  *DEAL_DETAILS* is 'completed' I would like to update the *status* in *DEALS* table as 'completed'.

**Giving an example-**

The **status** of **1013** in **DEALS** table should be 'completed'. As **ALL** **status**es of **1013** linked(Foreign Key) **dealid** in **DEAL_DETAILS** are in 'completed' status.

Whereas, that's not the case with **1012** as 2 are in 'completed' **status** and other 2 have different **status**. So, **status** in **DEALS** table should NOT be changed.

And, 1011 is out of question!

**My schema looks like this-**

**DEALS:**

[image]

**DEAL_DETAILS:**

[image]

I did try some SQL queries by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162355/check-if-all-conditions-specified-are-satisfied-in-sql-query), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147598/mysql-update-query-with-subquery-taking-forever), [this](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-any-all) and [this](http://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-21-using-subqueries-in-the-where-clause/). My query is incomplete and doesn't look good.
Currently, I have achieved the same inefficiently(I guess) using PHP(please ignore if there are change in column names).

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aggregateStatusresult)) {
    //$return_array[$i++] = $row;
    if(strcmp($row->status, 'completed') && (!(isset($statusarray[$row->dealid])) || ($statusarray[$row->dealid] != 'completed')))
        $statusarray[$row->dealid] = 'completed';
    else
        $statusarray[$row->dealid] = $row->status;
}
foreach($statusarray  as $dealid => $status){
    $updateAggregateStatus = "update deals d set d.status='".$status."' where d.dealid = '".$dealid."'";
    $updateAggregateStatusresult = $connection->query($updateAggregateStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle it with a simple `NOT EXISTS` check:

```
UPDATE deals d SET d.status='approved'
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deal_details
    WHERE deal_details.dealid = d.id AND status <> 'completed');
```

This assumes there are always rows in the `deal_details` table, if there are none it will mark the deal approved.

Comment: Thanks. This simply worked. I just had to make few more changes to the query to suit very specific purpose.